# Populate element with details for given ids

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkbox options

```
<div id="myList">
    <input id="item_51" type="checkbox" value="51" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_51">item 51 value</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item_55" type="checkbox" value="55" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_55">some other value</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item_58" type="checkbox" value="58" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_58">another value</label>
    <br>
    ...
</div>
```

Now, when I load the contents of the site I have other elements that contain data attribute with the matching values.

```
<div id="em1" class="myEm" data-items="55">...</div>
<div id="em4" class="myEm"  data-items="51,58">...</div>
<div id="em31" class="myEm" data-items="55,58">...</div>
```

I need to get the values of the checkbox labels to populate element divs when numbers in `data-items` match checkbox values.

If it was just one item to match I'd have no problem but I'm a bit confused with multples. So I assume I start by looping through items that have data-items values

```
$('.myEm').each(function() {

    var matchEm = $(this).attr('data-items'),
        matchCh = $('#myList input:checkbox').val(matchEm);

    $(this).text(matchCh);

});
```

Expected result for `<div id="em31" class="myEm" data-items="55,58">...</div>` will be:

```
<div id="em31" class="myEm" data-items="55,58">some other value, another value</div>
```

Comment: What is expected text of  `.myEm` having `data-items="55,58"` ?

Comment: @ guest271314 Good question. I've updated the question; put clarification at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `.split()` , `.map()` , `$.inArray()` , `.get()`

```js
$('.myEm').each(function() {

    var matchEm = $(this).attr('data-items').split(","),
        matchCh = $('#myList input:checkbox').map(function(i, el) {
                    return $.inArray(el.value, matchEm) !== -1 
                           ? el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML : null
                  }).get();

    $(this).text(matchCh.join(", "));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myList">
    <input id="item_51" type="checkbox" value="51" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_51">item 51 value</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item_55" type="checkbox" value="55" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_55">some other value</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item_58" type="checkbox" value="58" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_58">another value</label>
    <br>
    ...
</div>

<div id="em1" class="myEm" data-items="55">...</div>
<div id="em4" class="myEm"  data-items="51,58">...</div>
<div id="em31" class="myEm" data-items="55,58">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd loop through your classes and split the string in the `data=items` attribute, then loop through those strings and append to the current `<div>`.

```js
$('.myEm').each(function() {

  var myEm = $(this);
  var matchEm = $(this).attr('data-items').split(',');
  
  matchEm.forEach(function(value) {
    var label = $('#myList label[for="item_' + value + '"]').text();
    if (myEm.text().length === 0)
      myEm.append(label);
    else
      myEm.append(", " + label);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myList">
    <input id="item_51" type="checkbox" value="51" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_51">item 51 value</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item_55" type="checkbox" value="55" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_55">some other value</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item_58" type="checkbox" value="58" name="item[]">
    <label for="item_58">another value</label>
    <br>
</div>

<div id="em1" class="myEm" data-items="55"></div>
<div id="em4" class="myEm"  data-items="51,58"></div>
<div id="em31" class="myEm" data-items="55,58"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you change data-items from "51,58" to "51 58", you can use the [attribute contains word selector `~=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) and do something like this.

```
$('#myList input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var temp = this;
    $('.myEm[data-items~=' + temp.value + ']').each(function(){
        var text = $('label[for=' + temp.id + ']').text();
        var currentText = $(this).text();
        if(currentText.length != 0)
          currentText = currentText + ', ' + text;
        else
          currentText = text;
        $(this).text(currentText);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjfhpffg/

Comment: I almost suggested this solution, but didn't want to force him to change his attributes. A good solution though if he's willing to do that.

Comment: I thought exactly the same, but considering those are dynamic values apparently, so why not use ~= i thought. good point nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of the values in your checkboxes:

```js
$('#myList').on('change', function() {
    var Vals = [];
    $('input[name="item[]"]:checked').each(function() {
        var strName = 'str' + $(this).val()
        Vals[strName] = $(this).next('label').text();
    });
    $('.myEm').each(function() {
        var myVals = $(this).attr('data-items').split(',');
        var strText = '';
        $.each(myVals, function(index, value) {            
            if (Vals['str' + value]) {
                if (strText != '') {
                    strText += ', '                   
                }
                strText += Vals['str' + value]
            }
        });
        $(this).text(strText);
    });
});
```

```css
.myEm {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2px 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myList">
    <input id="item_51" type="checkbox" value="51" name="item[]" />
    <label for="item_51">item 51 value</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="item_55" type="checkbox" value="55" name="item[]" />
    <label for="item_55">some other value</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="item_58" type="checkbox" value="58" name="item[]" />
    <label for="item_58">another value</label>
    <br/>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="em1" class="myEm" data-items="55">1</div>
<div id="em4" class="myEm"  data-items="51,58">2</div>
<div id="em31" class="myEm" data-items="55,58">3</div>
```

And here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gpgf25b) just for good measure.